workbench.developerforce.com object list drop down is crashing
When trying to select https://workbench.developerforce.com/select.php is getting an Aw, Snap! error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT.
It seems the page is crashing.
I tried the following
Checked internet connection
deleted cache
tried incognito
closed all tabs
Any ideas what is going on with Workbench?
Steps to recreate issue.

login to https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php  API Version 58.0
Jump to:  SOQL Query
Object:  (am not able to select one the window comes up blank and page crashes).

I am able to write SOQL queries manually.  But am unable to view anything on the entire website that has a drop down to objects

When I go to the workbench, I don't even see select.php as one of the available pages. When I manually put that into my address bar, I don't see the error you're seeing. How are you getting there? What environment/API version are you using to login? The more details you can provide, the better. You should [edit] your question to include more details.

And also, keep in mind that: 1) We're not an official part of Salseforce here (99% of us are Salesforce customers). 2) The workbench isn't an official Salesforce thing. 3) Even if this is an actual issue, the workbench project is in maintenence-only mode, so it wouldn't be fixed.

Thanks, Derek. I know it isn't official, but if you have any ideas, it would be great.

About the only things that come to mind are perhaps you don't have access to all of your org's objects (maybe you don't have the sysadmin profile?), maybe you have a managed package that you don't have access to, or maybe you deployed a new SObject to your org but haven't set up permissions/FLS for it (permissions and FLS do not get deployed alongside the SObject).

I am an admin. I don't think that would cause the site to crash.  I think it might be we have too many objects to load. I will check there is no access issue as well.

Do you find any solution for this issue? I am also facing the same issue when I : login to https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php API Version 58.0 Jump to: SOQL Query
Object: (am not able to select one the window comes up blank and page crashes). like this : 

I am having the same issue since 06/14/24 around 330 eastern time , cannot use the dropdown to select an object on SOQL Query, or Update/Insert functions.  Just get the same Status Breakpoint Error.   I have been able to use it from a different computer on the same internet connection so I am THINKING this might have something to do with the specific version of chrome that I am running on my work computer is probably a version older than my personal computer where I always run Canary version of Edge.
I found a clue which I have attached from the developer console in chrome, it shows a deprecated feature trying to be used which it says it won't use.
"Unload event listeners are deprecated and will be removed.
1 source
wz_tooltip.js:230


I'm not sure what the issue was but I notice the problem is no longer occurring.

I was having similar error messages in two other areas (see: Chrome "Aw, Snap! error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT" occurring in 3 different scenarios)
I have confirmed that updating Chrome to (at least) Version 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) will resolve the error(s).
